# TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type y which has no callable sqrt method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

Почему у меня не считает дифференциальное уравнение?
Это Бернулли. Вот само уравнение: xy′ − 2y − x2 * sqrt(y) = 0
Вот мой код:

```
from sympy import *
from scipy import *
import numpy as np

x = symbols('x')
y = symbols('y', cls=Function)
result = dsolve(Eq(y(x).diff(x), x * y(x).diff(x) - 2 * y(x) - x**2 * np.sqrt(y(x))), 0)
print('1.4.1')
pprint(result)
```

Вот traceback:
[image: traceback]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ругается оно явно на `np.sqrt`, на простой корень `sqrt` заменить не помогает, остаётся ошибка, хоть и другая уже. Но можно для квадратного корня использовать такое написание в питоне `**0.5` и так уже не ругается:

```
result = dsolve(Eq(y(x).diff(x), x * y(x).diff(x) - 2 * y(x) - x**2 * y(x)**0.5), 0)
```

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло, вот ошибка: sympy.core.function.PoleError: Cannot expand gamma(_x - 1.0) around 0

Comment: @Iangyl Странно, у меня в Google Colab этот код прекрасно работает

Comment: Действительно всё работает в Colab. Я так же попробовал pow использовать, но оно же по сути тоже самое выходит. И поэтому и ошибка та же была. Я в VS Code работаю.

Comment: @Iangyl Скорее всего в колабе другие версии библиотек, сверьте со своими версиями

Comment: Я обновил версии библиотек до последних в VS Code - ошибка та же.

Comment: @Iangyl Нет, надо именно сравнить версии. Экосистема питона - штука сложная. Последние версии - не гарантия, что всё совместимо и одинаково. Ну и кроме того, вам надо убедиться, что VS Code подхватывает именно то окружение питона, которое вы обновили (их несколько может быть на компьютере)